# how do I do to not cause a red underline of props from reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

```
const Residence = (`*props*`) => {
  return (
    <div className="img-container">
      <img src={`*props.image*`} width="300px" />
      <span>{`*props.price*`}</span>
      <h4>{`*props.name*`}</h4>
      <p>{`*props.description*`}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Residence;
```

Those in `italics` are getting a red underline.

I want to get rid of those red underlines in props, can someone please help me fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I not sure, but your issue may come from the `propTypes` declaration.

`eslint` basic configuration for ReactJS, make propTypes declaration obligatory.

To do it, install the module `prop-types`, if it is not already installed. (prop-types documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types)

```bash
npm install prop-types
```

And add the following code to your component file.

```
import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"

const Residence = (props) => {
  return <>
    <img src={props.image} width="300px" /> 
    {props.price} 
    {props.name}
    {props.description}
  </>;
};
Reisdent.propTypes = {
  image: PropTypes.string,
  price: PropTypes.number,
  name: PropTypes.string,
  description: PropTypes.string,
}

export default Residence;
```

If this doesn't help, you could you please say what is your error.

Comment: still it didn't work, still have red underline on these props   :(